# Visual Studio 2017 Performance Profiler: A required privilege is not held by the client

Tags: visual-studio, performance

I'm trying to run the Performance Profiler wizard on a sample app I have (something I'm using for a demo -- it just counts words in a text file.  The app works fine.).  I have the thing in Release mode, and I've gone through the wizard.  But when it starts I get the following:

```
Profiling started.
Profiling process ID 11984 (ProfilingDemo).
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
Starting data collection. The output file is C:\Users\RothAM\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ProfilingDemo\ProfilingDemo181129.vspx
Profiler stopping.
   at Diagnostics.Eventing.TraceEventSession.EnableKernelProvider(Keywords flags, Keywords stackCapture)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PerformanceTools.Base.VSPerf.Main(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PerformanceTools.VSPerfEtwMon.VSPerfEtwMon.Run()
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: A required privilege is not held by the client. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070522)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PerformanceTools.VSPerfEtwMon.VSPerfEtwMon.Start()
Error starting data collection with a dedicated process C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools\VSPerf.
PRF0025: No data was collected.
Profiling complete.
```

Worse, once it dies I can't start up the profiler again.  And there's a suspended process for devenv.exe that I can't kill either, via taskkill, proccess explorer, or task manager.

Diagnostics works just fine.  If I don't bother with the Performance Wizard I'm good to go and can get information.  It's the wizard that kills anything.

I'm running VS as an admin.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am having this same issue. I am on a work computer and expecting its some company policy preventing some elevated access permission.